# What does -webkit-line-box-contain do?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I recently saw this style used in a webpage.

```
<span style="-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced">A</span>
```

I found out that with and without this style , the content renders the same way in chrome.
I couldnt find any clear explanation for this style on the web.
Could someone help me ?

Comment: Google Search found https://github.com/ftlabs/ftcolumnflow/issues/2 - It's about to be deprecated in Chromw as I understand - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/rKDXtqvgDv4/1Q5ByQllDAAJ